# Birkhoff average of $x \mapsto x+1$ in $\mathbb R$ with $L^p$ observable

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory

Let $f \in \mathcal L^p(\mathbb R, \lambda)$, where $\lambda$ is Lebesgue measure and $p \in (1,\infty)$. And let $T : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ be the map $T(x) = x+1$. I want to show: 
$$
\frac 1 n \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} f \circ T^k \xrightarrow{L^p} 0 \quad \textrm{as } n \to \infty.
$$
This exercise is coming from a probability theory textbook, so I want to avoid advanced tools from ergodic theory. I can show the $n$th Birkhoff average is in $\mathcal L^p$, but I'm having trouble proving anything about this sequence of $\mathcal L^p$ functions (Cauchy, a.e. convergent, etc.). Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First note the result is obvious if $f$ is compactly supported. Then, since compactly supported functions are dense, we are done if we can get a bound of the form $||\frac{1}{N}\sum_{n \le N} f(\cdot+n)||_p \le C ||f||_p$ with $C$ independent of $f$ and $N$. But we can get $C=1$ by triangle inequality.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I might try using the simple function argument without using Minkowski's inequality, only because that hasn't appeared yet in the textbook I'm referencing. Fingers crossed.

Comment: @DFord do you mean proving the result is true for $f$ simple?

Comment: @DFord if so, I edited my answer to make life easier for you

Comment: Well, the argument via simple functions or compactly supported ones still uses the $L^p$ triangle inequality, a.k.a. Minkowski's inequality. Since this theorem isn't proven in this textbook until the following section, I'd like to avoid it if possible.

Comment: @DFord the textbook hasn't proven that $||\cdot||_p$ is a norm?? also, you should be precise with language. you should say "the argument showing that the result for simple functions implies the result for all $L^p$ functions" rather than just saying "the argument via simple functions"

Comment: not at this point in the book, no. Of course, the exercise could be misplaced.

Comment: @DFord What a weird book, to work with $||\cdot||_p$ and talk about convergence before proving (or stating) that $||\cdot||_p$ is a norm. In any event, are you happy with the following: $||\frac{1}{N}\sum_{n \le N} T^n f||_p \le ||f||_p$ for $p=1$ and $p=\infty$, so it holds for all intermediate $p$ by (Marcinkiewicz) interpolation.

Comment: Note that it fails for $p=1$, with the easy counterexample given by the indicator function on the unit interval. Hence the “obvious” statement fails for $p=1$ as well. Interestingly it also fails for $p=\infty$ with 1 being the counterexample (though compactly supported functions are clearly not dense in that case).

Comment: @Shalop Ah, my apologies. Thanks for bringing this to my attention! So if $f$ has compact support, then clearly $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} f(x+k)$ tends to $0$ pointwise as $n \to \infty$. But also, for each $n$, $|\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} f(x+k)| \lesssim \frac{||f||_\infty}{x}$ as $x \to \infty$ and so is dominated by an $L^p$ function (for $p > 1$). Hence, dominated convergence theorem applies for $p > 1$.